# how to create dynamic PFUser objects in parse?

Tags: dynamic-data, parse-platform

**Scenario** :- I used Parse facebook Login in my app.
     In my application UserA sends cookie to UserB? i want to store how many cookies UserA sent to UserB. also when UserB logs in he should be notified that how many cookies he received.I want to store and fetch these values through parse.UserA can send cookies to as many friends as he wants and all those friends should get updated about received number of cookies.

**Possible Solution** :-     so for each friend of UserA 2 Objects should be created dynamically

```
 a)sent number of cookies
 b)received number of cookies
```

And when those friends login they fetch their own received-request-object on parse.

**Problem** :- i cant update the UserB objects from UserA login. since `[PFUser currentUser]` would only allow me to update UserA Objects and not UserB Objects.

I am new to programming and i dont want to create my own web-service backEnd.
Can I do this with Parse or should I try something Else?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to learn about relational data, mentioned in the Parse website: https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-pointers/iOS

Basically you will need to create a new class for Cookie, add a new object of Cookie, set the relationship of the object to the sender (a PFUser object), and set another relationship to the receiver (another PFUser object).

```
PFObject *cookie = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Cookie"];

PFUser *sender = [PFUser currentUser];
PFRelation *sendingRelation = [sender relationforKey:@"sends"];
[sendingRelation addObject:cookie];

PFUser *receiver = //friend PFUser object;
PFRelation *receivingRelation = [receiver relationforKey:@"receives"];
[receivingRelation addObject:cookie];
```

Then you can use the relational query to get the number of sent or received cookies: https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-relational/iOS

Comment: what is friend PFUser Object exactly (a unique number, string or something else) and how could friend PFUser access the cookie object object of receivingRelation?